Combining repo name search with keyword and finding a specific term in them query on github search
I want to search for a term/url in a codebase(repo) conatining name "voice" on github search example: look for all reponames containing voice then list out the url containing ones
I tried query "voice in:name search term" but it worked as a or statement and listed out all the repos with voice and voice containing the search term while i wanted it to work as and i.e repo names containing voice in their name and search term in them
